# What is wrong with this iCal event?

Tags: icalendar

I'm generating an ics file from calendar information and google calendar can show these. But a few events doesn't show up, for example this one: (one event extracted from the full file)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//tt.megy.se//CalendarExporter V0.1//SE
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Tick-Tack
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20120116T095000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20120116T095000Z
CREATED:20120116T095000Z
SEQUENCE:1
DTSTART:20120116T095000Z
DTEND:20120116T104000Z
UID:Lesson20120116T095000ZLu111D@tt.megy.se
SUMMARY:Lunch
LOCATION:.
URL:http://tt.megy.se
DESCRIPTION:.
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have checked the above at http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ and it validates. Does anyone have any idea why this specific event wouldn't  show up in an iCal consumer, for example google calendar.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "import" it into a test google calendar with no problem.
In my experience, "subscribing" via google calendar can be slow - ie it may not show up for a while.